TikZ-PGF surface edges smoothing
I have this surface I plotted using Latex but the edge is ragged. Anyone knows how to fix that? I tried increasing the number of samples but the raggedness persists and the computing time becomes too much.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots, nicefrac, subfig, caption}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[p]
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        view={67.5}{30}, 
        xmin=0, xmax=1, xtick={0,0.33,0.66,1},  xticklabels={0,$\nicefrac{1}{3}$,$\nicefrac{2}{3}$,1}, xlabel=$s_{1}$,
        ymin=0, ymax=1, ytick={0,0.33,0.66,1},  yticklabels={0,$\nicefrac{1}{3}$,$\nicefrac{2}{3}$,1}, ylabel=$s_{2}$,
        zmin=0.01, zmax=1.2, zlabel={$H(s_{i})$}, every axis z label/.style={at={(ticklabel cs:1.05)}, anchor=south}, minor z tick num=1,
        colormap/cool, colorbar, 
        domain=0:1, restrict z to domain=0:1.2,
        samples=50,  ]
    \addplot3[surf, ]    {-x*ln(x) - y*ln(y) - (1-x-y)*ln(1-x-y)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}


I tried increasing number of samples but didn't really help (just lead to crashing more than anything else)

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

There is no automatic way to avoid that problem - the function is evaluated on a regular mesh. Here is one way to get a better result:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
view={67.5}{30}, 
xmin=0, xmax=1,
ymin=0, ymax=1,
zmin=0, zmax=1.2,
colormap/cool,
line join=round,
]
\begin{scope}
\clip (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1.2) -- (0,1,1.2) -- (0,1,0) -- plot[domain=0:1, samples=20, smooth] (\x,{1-\x},{-\x*ln(\x)-(1-\x)*ln(1-\x)}) -- (1,0,0) --cycle;
\addplot3[
surf,
domain=0:1, samples=50,
z filter/.expression={1-x-y<0?0:z},
%unbounded coords=jump,
] {-x*ln(x) - y*ln(y) - (1-x-y)*ln(1-x-y)};
\end{scope}
\addplot3[mesh, domain=0:1, samples=50, samples y=1, forget plot] (\x,{1-\x},{-\x*ln(\x)-(1-\x)*ln(1-\x)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Fabulous. Thank you!!!

No need to write thank you -but please accept the answer.
